# How to get Symbols from Excel to Word using Mail Merge

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, mailmerge, vba

I have an `Excel` sheet which contains lots of data..Some fields contains Symbol data, while other contains String and integer Data.

I have a written a java program that takes Data from EXCEL sheet and puts it into the Word File using `Mail Merge`. The Whole thing works fine but when it comes to `Symbols` Images it takes their value but does not pick up the actual image that i need to put into the document.

Kindly guide me how to pick up the image that is visible in Excel sheet rather than its actual Value.

The Word File shows `þ` rather than the `Tick or Cross` image that is visible in the Excel Sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this might be down to the font you are using and because Word is very finicky when it comes to transferring over symbols in this way.

I would suggest using a Wingdings font value that matches the symbol you need - and filling in the Excel document with that value. This may be already how Excel is dealing with the issue

In Wingdings 2 - the symbols you want are capital R & S - so you simply need to change the part in word that should be ticks/crosses to match this font I would imagine.